# How to execute SQL statement returned by user defined Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I created user defined function which is returning CLOB value. How to execute the SQL statement that the CLOB contains?

Answer (score 2):

If your SQL statement could be more than 32K-bytes long it won't fit in a string, which it must do if you use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. If your statement is longer than 32K you can still execute it by using the functions in the DBMS_SQL package. A good basic example of DBMS_SQL use can be found [here (java2s.com)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0601__System-Packages/Printtablewithdynamicquery.htm). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  See for example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm